# How to set up a DLL search path for Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have a C# application that uses a managed C++ DLL, which in turn depends on some native DLLs. The native DLLs are in a subdirectory. Before the application loads the managed DLL, it sets the PATH environment variable to include the subdirectory, so that the DLL can be loaded. This works fine.

But ReSharper now marks all references to my managed DLL as red. This is (I think) because the managed DLL cannot be loaded by Resharper, as it cannot find the native DLLs it depends on.

So you can I fix that? Some ideas:

- One solution would be to modify the PATH environment variable system-wide. But the path needs to be different depending on the configuration (Debug/Release). So switching configuration would require to close VS, change the PATH and restart VS. Not very practical....
- I could set the PATH in a batch script that then starts VisualStudio. I would need two (one for Release, one for Debug). A bit better but still not very practical. And somehow it does not work, not sure why. Does Resharper not inherit the environment variables from VS?
- Include both debug and release (sub)directories into the system PATH and use different names for the DLLs, so the right ones are loaded. Would work, but the DLLs are from a third party, renaming them all is something I would like to avoid.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Somehow it works now. I was setting the PATH system-wide but now removed the additional search path again and it still works. Probably Resharper has it cached.

Comment: Another idea: make the native DLLs to load delayed. Maybe this is enough so Resharper can load the managed DLL and figure out the interface (with out loading the native DLLs it depends on). Will test it when I have some time...